# Egr valve cleaning (2.0Tdi 2005)

Tags: diesel, tdi, egr, seat-cars

I would like to give my cars egr valve a good cleaning.

I have seen a few YouTube videos and they can get fairly caked up.

Would it be recommended to clean it by submerging it in petrol for a few days, to loosen up the carbon deposits, are there any parts that this would be an issue for?

I can't see any sensors, etc,that would be damaged during this process if I did it.

Comment: What make of VW?

Comment: It's a seat altea 2005 tdi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take it off of the engine, your best bet is to clean it with carb cleaner. Don't submerge it in anything, as you can cause damage to any diaphragm seals which may be present (if vacuum operated) or in any electrical motors which do the work.

Also, when you clean it, don't forget to clean the ports in the intake manifold. They will also be clogged. If the EGR is plugged or gummed up, you'll need to clean the ports to get it function correctly/efficiently.